# Checking if an array is element of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 13 python NumPy arrays:

```
obj_1=np.array([784,785,786,787,788,789,790,791,792])
obj_2=np.array([716,717,718,730,731,732,721,722,724,726,727])
obj_3=np.array([658,659,660,661,662,663,664,665])
obj_4=np.array([581,582,583,589,590,591,595,597,598,599,601,605,606,613,614])
obj_5=np.array([533,534,535,536,537])
obj_6=np.array([464,469,472,474])
obj_7=np.array([406,409,411,412])
obj_8=np.array([345,346,347,349])
obj_9=np.array([277,278,281,282,283,284,288,296])
obj_10=np.array([217,219,220,223,224])
obj_11=np.array([154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161])
obj_12=np.array([91,92,93,94,95,96,97])
obj_13=np.array([28,29,30,31,32,33,34])
```

Then the following loop:

```
for i in [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9, obj_10, obj_11, obj_12, obj_13]:
    print i in [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9]
```

I would expect this output:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
```

Instead I get the following with an error:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-221-c03c1ef308c6>", line 16, in <module>
print i in [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9]

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use  a.any() or a.all()
```

I tested different arrays with the same names and the same for loop; they produced no error.

It seems like the problem lies in the content of the arrays, but I couldn't figure out where.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: do you mean a subset? You do know `obj_1` to `obj_9` are always going to be in the list of array? 10,11,12,13 are the only ones you don't have in it

Comment: You probably need `.tolist()` but I really don't see what you are trying to do

Comment: I can't see how this error could have come from this code - you don't seem to be checking the truth value of any arrays.

Comment: I edited my question, i hope my problem is clearer now? Thanks for your fast responses!!

Comment: This is fascinating. `obj_3 in [obj_6]` is `False` but `obj_7 in [obj_6]` throws the error...

Comment: Fascinating and a bit frustrating. `obj_8 in [obj_6]` throws the error too, the rest gives `False` or `True`. Are `obj_7` and `obj_8` somehow corrupt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `obj in list` python compares `obj` for equality with each of the members of list. The problem is that the equality operator in numpy doesn't behave in a consistent way. For example:

```
>>> obj_3 == obj_6
False
```

because they have different lengths, a boolean is returned.

```
>>> obj_7==obj_6
array([False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

because they have the same length, the arrays are compared element wise and a numpy array is returned. In this case the truth value is undetermined. It looks like this strange behaviour is going to [change in the future](http://numpy-tst.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release.html#object-array-equality-comparisons).

The correct way to do it would be to compare individually each pair of arrays using for example [numpy.array_equal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
for i in [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9, obj_10, obj_11, obj_12, obj_13]:
    print any(np.array_equal(i, j) for j in [obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9])
```

gets you:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
False
False
False
```

Comment: Ah yea that must be it. To explain further: `a` in `[b, c, d]` essentially checks `bool(a==b)`, `bool(a==c)`, `bool(a==d)`, and if `a` and `c` have the same length, it returns an array, whose truth value can't be determined.

Comment: I think this is correct but, to be pedantic, it seems that `id` (or something similar) is used to compare the arrays _before_ the test for equality. For example, `obj_1 in [obj_1]` returns `True` even though `bool(obj_1 == obj_1)` raises an error. The test for equality doesn't happen first.