# Finding the index of a numpy array in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

```
import numpy as np
foo = [1, "hello", np.array([[1,2,3]]) ]
```

I would expect

```
foo.index( np.array([[1,2,3]]) )
```

to return

```
2
```

but instead I get

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

anything better than my current solution? It seems inefficient.

```
def find_index_of_array(list, array):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if np.all(list[i]==array):
            return i

find_index_of_array(foo, np.array([[1,2,3]]) )
# 2
```

Comment: Very very interesting.

Comment: Is the non-homogenous list just as an example, or do you really have a list with many different types in it?

Comment: @mgilson just my contrived example. I am working with a list of numpy arrays of equal dimension

Comment: Could you recast this to use `is` instead of `==` for the comparison?

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- it turns out that if you use the same array, numpy python _will_ do the right thing.  `lst = [array]; lst.find(array)  # 0`.  The reason for this is because `is` checks are lightning fast (pointer comparisons) and since it's fairly common to search for something in a list that you already have a reference to, python does an `is` comparison before falling back to the `==` comparison.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27696763/checking-if-an-array-is-element-of-a-list-of-arrays/27697254#27697254 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488307/numpy-array-in-python-list

Comment: @mgilson. Yes, except that only works out of the box for a single-element array. I was just wondering if that would help OP's real problem since it is possible  he is searching with  an instance already in the list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- No, it works out of the box for arrays of arbitrary size.  e.g. in my example (when I tested it locally), `array = np.array([1,2,3])` and it works fine.

Comment: @mgilson. I messed up. I meant single element lists, or more specifically lists where the target array is not the first element . otherwise you will invoke == at least once because is will be false.

Comment: @MadPhysicist -- Ahh yes, that makes sense.  You're right.  Good point.

Comment: @Lee88 So, **all elements** in input list are NumPy arrays?

Comment: @Divakar yes, of all equal dimension as well. Sorry for the unnecessarily complex example. I learned a lot from your idea of checking the type beforehand.

Comment: Interestingly, also happens if you're not looking for an array as long as you have to look past the array. e.g.`["a", np.arange(3), "b"].index("b")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason for the error here is obviously because numpy's ndarray overrides `==` to return an array rather than a boolean.

AFAIK, there is no simple solution here.  The following will work so long as the 
`np.all(val == array)` bit works.

```
next((i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if np.all(val == array)), -1)
```

Whether that bit works or not depends critically on what the other elements in the array are and if they can be compared with numpy arrays.

Comment: Note that this is not identical to `list.index` which throws a `ValueError` when there is no such item. But good and simple solution!

Comment: @MSeifert -- Yeah.  I was going for an API that is a little more like `str.find`.  If you want an exception then you can just drop the `-1` part (only passing the generator to `next`).  In that case, you'll get a `StopIteration` if it wasn't found.

Answer (score 3):

How about this one?

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3]])
foo = np.array([1, 'hello', arr], dtype=np.object)

# if foo array is of heterogeneous elements (str, int, array)
[idx for idx, el in enumerate(foo) if type(el) == type(arr)]

# if foo array has only numpy arrays in it
[idx for idx, el in enumerate(foo) if np.array_equal(el, arr)]
```

**Output:**

```
[2]
```

Note: This will also work even if `foo` is a list. I just put it as a `numpy` array here.

Comment: OP said in comments that the real list will only contain arrays, so this will be a preprocessing step at best.

Comment: Technically, the first method only works reliably if there is exactly one array in the list, and you know up-front that that array is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Isn't the OP's question asking for the index of *a* numpy array?

Comment: No. OP's question is how to get the `==` comparator to return a boolean with numpy arrays so he can find the correct index, as in your second solution.

Answer (score 2):

For performance, you might want to process only the NumPy arrays in the input list. So, we could type-check before going into the loop and index into the elements that are arrays.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def find_index_of_array_v2(list1, array1):
    idx = np.nonzero([type(i).__module__ == np.__name__ for i in list1])[0]
    for i in idx:
        if np.all(list1[i]==array1):
            return i
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's list consists of only numpy arrays to begin with (based on comments), so this will provide more overhead than optimization.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Really? I thought OP has a sample of `foo = [1, "hello", np.array([[1,2,3]]) ]`, which is a mixed one. I missed that mention of `".. list consists of only numpy arrays"`?

Comment: Yeah. Third comment on the question. It makes sense that OP wanted the most generic answer, which is why he asked with the contrived array, but it does throw a damper on your answer unfortunately.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I will keep it for future readers who might have a mixed form as input list. Might be useful for them.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here (you probably know already but just to repeat it) is that `list.index` works along the lines of:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(your_list):
    if item == wanted_item:
        return idx
```

The line `if item == wanted_item` is the problem, because it implicitly converts `item == wanted_item` to a boolean. But `numpy.ndarray` (except if it's a scalar) raises this `ValueError` then:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

## Solution 1: adapter (thin wrapper) class

I generally use a thin wrapper (adapter) around `numpy.ndarray` whenever I need to use python functions like `list.index`:

```
class ArrayWrapper(object):

    __slots__ = ["_array"]  # minimizes the memory footprint of the class.

    def __init__(self, array):
        self._array = array

    def __eq__(self, other_array):
        # array_equal also makes sure the shape is identical!
        # If you don't mind broadcasting you can also use
        # np.all(self._array == other_array)
        return np.array_equal(self._array, other_array)

    def __array__(self):
        # This makes sure that `np.asarray` works and quite fast.
        return self._array

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._array)
```

These thin wrappers are more expensive than manually using some `enumerate` loop or comprehension but you don't have to re-implement the python functions. Assuming the list contains only numpy-arrays (otherwise you need to do some `if ... else ...` checking):

```
list_of_wrapped_arrays = [ArrayWrapper(arr) for arr in list_of_arrays]
```

After this step you can use all your python functions on this list:

```
>>> list_of_arrays = [np.ones((3, 3)), np.ones((3)), np.ones((3, 3)) * 2, np.ones((3))]
>>> list_of_wrapped_arrays.index(np.ones((3,3)))
0
>>> list_of_wrapped_arrays.index(np.ones((3)))
1
```

These wrappers are not numpy-arrays anymore but you have thin wrappers so the extra list is quite small. So depending on your needs you could keep the wrapped list and the original list and choose on which to do the operations, for example you can also `list.count` the identical arrays now:

```
>>> list_of_wrapped_arrays.count(np.ones((3)))
2
```

or `list.remove`:

```
>>> list_of_wrapped_arrays.remove(np.ones((3)))
>>> list_of_wrapped_arrays
[array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]), 
 array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2.]]), 
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])]
```

## Solution 2: subclass and [`ndarray.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html)

This approach uses explicit subclasses of `numpy.array`. It has the advantage that you get all builtin array-functionality and only modify the requested operation (which would be `__eq__`):

```
class ArrayWrapper(np.ndarray):
    def __eq__(self, other_array):
        return np.array_equal(self, other_array)

>>> your_list = [np.ones(3), np.ones(3)*2, np.ones(3)*3, np.ones(3)*4]

>>> view_list = [arr.view(ArrayWrapper) for arr in your_list]

>>> view_list.index(np.array([2,2,2]))
1
```

Again you get most list methods this way: `list.remove`, `list.count` besides `list.index`.

However this approach may yield subtle behaviour if some operation implicitly uses `__eq__`. You can always re-interpret is as plain numpy array by using `np.asarray` or `.view(np.ndarray)`:

```
>>> view_list[1]
ArrayWrapper([ 2.,  2.,  2.])

>>> view_list[1].view(np.ndarray)
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])

>>> np.asarray(view_list[1])
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

## Alternative: Overriding `__bool__` (or `__nonzero__` for python 2)

Instead of fixing the problem in the `__eq__` method you could also override `__bool__` or `__nonzero__`:

```
class ArrayWrapper(np.ndarray):
    # This could also be done in the adapter solution.
    def __bool__(self):
        return bool(np.all(self))

    __nonzero__ = __bool__
```

Again this makes the `list.index` work like intended:

```
>>> your_list = [np.ones(3), np.ones(3)*2, np.ones(3)*3, np.ones(3)*4]
>>> view_list = [arr.view(ArrayWrapper) for arr in your_list]
>>> view_list.index(np.array([2,2,2]))
1
```

But this will definitly modify more behaviour! For example:

```
>>> if ArrayWrapper([1,2,3]):
...     print('that was previously impossible!')
that was previously impossible!
```

Comment: I kept looking for a way to override the array class itself, but that wouldn't help with existing objects. Very nice solution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, one could also work with [`ndarray.view`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) and a subclass overriding `__eq__`. The steps remain the same, you need one pass to create a list of these views before applying the `list.index`-operations.

Comment: Yes, with the advantage that you could then use the subclass list as your only list without further modification to the surrounding code.

Comment: @MSeifert As a beginner to python, this was extremely useful to me from a teaching perspective. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
[i for i,j in enumerate(foo) if j.__class__.__name__=='ndarray']
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a view to override the equals method

```
import numpy as np

class Vector(np.ndarray):
    def __eq__(self, other: np.ndarray) -> bool:
        return np.array_equal(super(),other)

data=list(np.random.random((100,3)))
element=data[3]

print(data.index(element.view(Vector))) #prints 3
print(element.view(Vector) in data) #prints True
```